# What does the word "analogue" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a text about advantages of email in marketing. Kindly explain what does that [sentence](https://econsultancy.com/blog/67464-why-email-is-the-king-of-one-to-one-marketing) mean:

> Many in digital talk about email almost as it were analogue (tired and old hat).

Does the author compare it with tired and old hat? Then what is "digital"?

Answer (score 5):

The use of *analogue* in this context is loosely referring to pre-digital technology, such as the analog phones the people had hanging on their kitchen walls. The author is referring to a marketing movement, largely originating from the communications industry, in which the term "analog" referred to older technology, where "digital" meant new. The implication here is that email is old, it might as well be lumped into the same category as old analog phones.  It's not the best piece of prose written in the English language, so you have to squint a bit at what's being said to make sense of it.

Comment: That squinting has to do with it having a really rough and harrowing marketing smell as well. Or so the text feels. Analog in this regard is a marketing buzzword with a negative aftertaste - projecting.

Answer (score 0):

"Tired old hat" may possess a notion of cliché, [common place](http://studysite.org/dictionary/English-meaning-of-cliche), seen too much. A example is given [here](http://unleadedwriting.com/2016/01/09/cliches-are-the-worst-thing-ever/) for writers (of plots):

> you’ve used a plot that’s been done and done again, and that seems
>   tired (old hat!)

In your context , some consider (so-called "[digital natives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_native)") that email belongs to the past (of one-to-one marketing). Yet, they might as well:

> underestimate its power when combined with CRM, automation and great
>   creative

Digital natives are opposed to digital immigrants, or sometimes [analogue (analog) natives](https://www.academia.edu/1377452/Analogue_Natives). First emails indeed [date from the 1970's](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2002/cmsc434-0101/MUIseum/applications/firstemail.html). This digital novelty superseded analogue written letters. Since technologies are progressing at a fast pace, old digital now sounds analogue.